# Splitting data between two databases- one is archive, one is active

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm not sure the best way to design this, so here goes:

I'm tracking students, papers, attendance, and grades through a current semester (now) and through a past set of semesters for reporting. Tables are partly keyed by semester.

I've archived off old semesters to a second database because there is a lot of data and the backups were including that.

Now, I'm not sure how to design a workable solution if someone needs to search across multiple semesters.

For example, someone might search for student records across this semester and a few in the past. The way I have it now, I'd have to either copy some of the records to the current database for searching or combine the two db's with a Union.

What's a good way to handle this? SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're tracking grades for every class for every student at a major university, there is no need to archive anything. Keep them together in the same database. Expose a view of the current semester to "joe user" and require some additional security for history.

Comment: I've got about 26,000 writing records per semester and the db backups are pushing 16gb. This may not be a lot in the scheme of things, but it's filling up the server, and fast.

Comment: 16GB seems far too much space for only 26K records per semester. 10 years would be 20 semesters = 520K records. Divide 16GB by 520K and you get 30K PER RECORD. That cannot be correct. Surely it doesn't take 30K per record to store grade per student per course per semester. And if you have less than 10 years now, you're using more than 30K per record. Also, you don't need to back up unchanging data after it has been backed up. Back up only what has changed.

Comment: It's storing writing in text fields, which accounts for all the space. It's not just student records.